# Spring boot fails on Eclipse + Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

When I run my spring boot project I get this error related to sfl4j. It seams that it's not finding the dependencies. I tried to add those dependencies manually on my pom.xml (it should get from sprig boot dependencies) but then it just fails further because another dependencies... I tried to run the project on another machine and ran just fine. Really weird... Here is the stack trace error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/joran/JoranConfigurator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at br.senai.ms.talentos.TalentosApplication.main(TalentosApplication.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

==========================
Here is my entire pom.xml

`http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0`

```
<groupId>br.senai.ms</groupId>
<artifactId>talentos</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>talentos</name>
<description>Talentos</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>br.teste.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
        <version>3.7.4</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: In order for others to help you, please post the `pom.xml` file as well. I think this happens because of jars with conflicting versions. You might have `slf4j` dependency but, there are other dependencies that will have `slf4j` as their transitive dependency hence, you will end up with different versions.

Comment: Please share `pom.xml`

Comment: I updated with my pom.xml @Raf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete the .m2 directory and build the project again. This might take a bit longer to build as maven downloads all the jars again.

Comment: After removing my whole .m2 the application ran fine. Tks

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.